# Why can't I compile SDL on Mac for x86_64 using C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, sdl, codeblocks

I'm running on a Mac Mini, late 2012 (The latest), 64 bit, Intel Core i7 2.3 gHz HyperThreading x86_64, or so says my computer. I'm also using Code::blocks for the time being because help in Xcode (which I would prefer) is even more sparse because I am using C++.  That said, programming language of choice is C++, and will eventually expand into Objective-C++, but that's for another day.

The problem is this: I am trying to compile a program that will do I'm not quite sure what yet (it's a template, let's just say it's a game for now.) using SDL 1.2.15, which I have compiled from source on my Mac. (I did try using SDLmain.m and SDL.h, but that was full of Objective-C code, and as I could find no good information on whether I could code in C++ with these on the internet, I gave up.) The source I compiled seems to work just fine, Code::Blocks can compile it's tutorial just fine and it runs ok. However, I cannot seem to get my game template to work. It compiles fine, with no errors or warnings, but the linker does not do the same. Now, I'm really not sure what `ld` does, I just know that it links together code. (Anyone want to elaborate on that?) When Code::Blocks gets to it's linking step it fails with this message:

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in PyroLauncher ---------------

Cleaned "PyroLauncher - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in PyroLauncher ---------------

Compiling: App.cpp
Compiling: OnCleanup.cpp
Compiling: OnEvent.cpp
Compiling: OnInit.cpp
Compiling: OnLoop.cpp
Compiling: OnRender.cpp
Linking console executable: bin/Debug/PyroLauncher
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      App::OnInit()     in OnInit.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      App::OnInit()     in OnInit.o
  "_SDL_PollEvent", referenced from:
      App::OnExecute()     in App.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      App::OnCleanup()     in OnCleanup.o
  "_SDL_SetVideoMode", referenced from:
      App::OnInit()     in OnInit.o
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

Which has me seriously confused. I just know that ld can't find  for my native architecture x86_64. If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.
What I think the solutions may be: (I don't know how to do them, however.)
SDL is not compiled for 64 bit, and therefore cannot be compiled against with 64 bit code.
SDL is compiled for Objective-C, and therefore cannot be used with code in C++.
My code is 32 bit, SDL is 64 bit, and they are not compatible.

Comment: "I'm really not sure what ld does, I just know that it links together code. (Anyone want to elaborate on that?)"  ~ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29 says it better than I can. The compiler "compiles" each separate file (checks for erors and, if none, generates most of the assembly code), and the linker does the rest - where file A calls a routine from file B the linker will add the address of that function into the code which the compiler generated for file A (dito data).  The compiler works on single files, while the linker sees the whole project and stitches it together.

Comment: A more verbose build ouput would be useful, especially the linker line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand what is happening here? Your code is calling functions which the linker (ld) can't find.

The two main probabilities are that you either need to include some more files in your project, or that you need to define some macros.

Search through the project for the definition of `SDL_GetError()` (and the others). If you don't find it, then you need to find the file which declares it and include that.

If you do find it, then it will probably be surrounded by `#ifdef XXXX` and you will have to define `xxxx` in your project options (not in your code). Most good IDEs (I use NetBeans, with Cygwin for C+ development) will grey out the then contents of an `ifdef` if it isn't defined, so you can imemdiately see if that is the case.

Btw, have a look around the SDL website for installation instructions. Alternatively, your download might have a file called "Install" or "Install.txt", and may also have a Makefile. If it does, then in your IDE look for an option Project/New ... from existing makefile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer so far. Considering my experiences with SDL on Windows, it appears like you fail linking SDLmain.lib, is it possible?

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, I had really no idea what ld did until now. I compiled from source and also have installed homebrew and done `brew install sdl` which seemed to work ok. I think I'll try including the SDLmain.m and .h files in Xcode and see if those work. If anyone still wants to know, I'll see about getting the linker line and also the full output.

Comment: @PyroAVR The nicest way to thank on this site is with an up-vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the files SDLMain.m and SDLMain.h to your project. The SDLMain files contain glue code so SDL code can run on Mac OS X. You also need to link the Cocoa framework to your project. The Mac version of SDL is written in Cocoa so you need to link to Cocoa. Linking the Cocoa framework does not force you to use Objective-C. You can write your game in C++.

If you're looking for information on setting up SDL with Xcode 4, read the following article:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

Comment: Well, I have managed to include all the necessary files and whatnot, but the program will not compile. I switched over to Xcode, thanks to the tutorial mentioned by Mark. However, SDLmain.m has about 20 errors in it so says Xcode, so I suppose I'll have to wait for those to be fixed by the SDL team.  Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @PyroAVR eh, if you get errors it's probably on your end. SDL is pretty widely used (understatement).